# Array modifier start/end cap error

Tags: bezier-curves

When making a curve with a "Toggle cyclic" setting and setting object with modifiers curve an array, object overlaps with himself like on the picture. You would usually solve this with Start Cap and End Cap, but I seem to get an error each time wherever I place them. The error message is:Failed to set value
[image]

Comment: doesn't look like an error though... try rescaling the sample model.

Answer (score 2):

This can be usually done by checking the *First/Last* option.
But not here, because the *Curve modifier* takes effect *after* the *Array modifier*.
You can use the new (2.82+) *Weld modifier* to merge the vertices instead.

1. Array modifier to copy your objects
2. Curve modifier to bend the geometry
3. Weld modifier to merge the First/Last vertices

[image]